How to extract the old Windows 11 Home Product Key that came with the computer after a fresh install of Windows 11 Enterprise?
I have applied the Windows 11 Enterprise product key after a fresh installation. I wonder if there's a way to extract the Windows 11 Home product key that came with the computer because I could use that on a different machine. Thank you.

Most likely, you cannot. Keys can be stored in the UEFI for that computer, and they activate automatically. They cannot be transferred as they are OEM licenses.

The key corresponds to a particular machine, with description stored in Microsoft's database. It would not work on a different PC.

What operating system is running on the different machine? If this is Windows 10, then you can still upgrade to Windows 11 for free.

@LPChip Then is there a way to downgrade to Windows 11 Home?

@jeffrey - No, there isn’t. Why do you need the key? If you were to reinstall Windows it would automatically detect the Home key not Enterprise. The Home key cannot be used on another machine

And you probably activated the enterprise key now, it won't activate a second time on a different pc either.

@LPChip Once a Widnows license is activated, there's no way to transfer to another PC?

When you try to activate it, it will fail. You can call Microsoft and they may grand you one more activation manually.
